# Google Map return null object reference, when map implementing on recylerview in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, mvvm, android-databinding

I'm implementing google map on recylerview adapter but it return null object reference.

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference**

```
public class TripAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        TripAdapterBinding tripAdapterBinding;
        MapView mapView;
        GoogleMap gMap;

        TripAdapterViewHolder(TripAdapterBinding tripAdapterBinding) {
            super(tripAdapterBinding.itemTrip);
            this.tripAdapterBinding = tripAdapterBinding;
            setMap(tripAdapterBinding.map);
        }

        public void setMap(MapView map) {
            mapView = map;
            if (mapView != null)
            {
                mapView.onCreate(null);
                mapView.onResume();
                mapView.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            this.gMap = googleMap;
        }
```

There i'm call my holder to display data on map

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TripAdapter.TripAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {
            GoogleMap thisMap = holder.gMap;

            LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183);

            thisMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(startPoint)
                    .title("")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

            thisMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startPoint, 12));



        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MapException "," "+e.getMessage());
        }
        holder.bindTrip(tripLists.get(position));
    }
```

Comment: probably your `onMapReady` is called after you call `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: but mapView.getMapAsync(this); call when adapter is called

Comment: `onMapReady` is called asynchronously, when the map becomes ready. You have to wait for it before doing anything with a map

Comment: So how call `onMapReady` before `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: you can't do that. It is not you who calls `onMapReady`. System will call it when the map is ready. You have to rework the logic the way to do the map staff in or after `onMapReady` is called

Comment: Thanks man finally i resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use static map by displaying path.

[Static map image generate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)
Here you will get image of map which you can use to display in recycler view adapter.